# QDoc overwrite html files

Tags: qt, qt6, qdoc

I use qdoc for creating code documentation.
I can generate my documents from comments, but I need to delete the old generated files before replacing them with new ones.
As an illustration, when I execute the command `qdoc project.qdocconf`, it gives me the error message: "(qdoc) error: Output directory './html' exists but is not empty." How can I tell qdoc to overwrite html directory?

Note:

- I'm using *qdoc 6.5.1*

##### What did I do?

- I previously read the [qdoc documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdoc-guide-conf.html), but unfortunately, it wasn't much help to me.

Comment: [Minimal qdocconf file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdoc-minimum-qdocconf.html) defines `outputdir` as `html` but `imagedirs` with `./images`. Since the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/22-qdoc-configuration-generalvariables.html#outputdir) claims that the previous files will be deleted, maybe it is just expecting from you to define `outputdir` w/o dot-slash to overwrite it properly.

Comment: @dynerp project.qdocconf:25: (qdoc) error: Output directory 'html' exists but is not empty

Comment: It seems either it is a environment problem or a configuration issue. I'd say double-check the write permission or create a new minimal example and try on it, also in case of you're working on windows ensure the user name contains only english letters

Comment: @dynerp It's work on QDoc 5.15.2.